# Emulator shows quick save dialog when launched in Android Studio on Macbook pro

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When the emulator is run, the quick save dialog box is shown and choosing either option hangs the emulator launch.
Tried -

- adb restart
- delete all avds
- restart Android studio
- restart system

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating HAXM and Android studio solved the problem.